# Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.NetCore.retail.amd64 not working on windows server

Tags: .net-core, ssas, windows-server, azure-analysis-services, adomd.net

I have installed the following package Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.NetCore.retail.amd64 on a .Net 6 app, in order to connect to an OlapCube.
The connection works fine from the local machine, I don't have any issues.
The app also runs on ISS on Windows Server, once I moved all the changes there, I'm getting the following error

```
This feature is supported for a .NET Core client only on Windows systems and requires that the .NET Core Desktop framework is installed.
```

I've installed .Net Desktop runtime on the Windows Server, but is still not working. I get the same error. I also restarted the server after installing the runtime.
Any ideas of what I might miss?
Here is the list of the runtimes that are installed there

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.24 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.28 
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.24 
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.28 
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.24
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.28
```

```
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.HttpStream.ChannelOptions..ctor(ConnectionInfo info, UserContext& context)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.HttpStream.HttpChannelManager.GetControllerAndUserContext(ConnectionInfo info, CookieContainer cookieContainer, HttpChannelController& controller, UserContext& context)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.HttpStream.Create(IConnectivityOwner owner, ConnectionInfo info, XmlaDataType desiredRequestType, XmlaDataType desiredResponseType, Int32 readTimeout, Boolean& isSessionTokenNeeded)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.OpenHttpConnection(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean& isSessionTokenNeeded)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.OpenConnectionAndCheckIfSessionTokenNeeded(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.<>c__DisplayClass169_0.<OpenConnection>b__0()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Security.TransparentUserContext.ExecuteInUserContextImpl[TResult](Func`1 action)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Security.UserContext.ExecuteInUserContext[TResult](Func`1 action)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.OpenConnection(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean& isSessionTokenNeeded)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.Connect(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean beginSession)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Connect()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.IXmlaClientProviderEx.ConnectXmla()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.ConnectToXMLA(Boolean createSession, Boolean isHTTP)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.Open()
   at PAS.BusinessLogic.Services.AnalysisService.DiscoverData(PivotDataSourceRequest request)
```